# How to print the background image completely and only once after printing the browser on each page?

Tags: html, printing-web-page

I have an invoice whose background is displayed only once on the browser screen and is not repeated.(Everything is fine.)

After printing: Part of the background image is printed on the first page and another part is printed on the second page. (In fact, image printing is corrupted)
I want the background image to be printed completely and only once per page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you may need to update config:

- paper size
- margins
- scale